# How to find if a value is in nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

`var array = [["1", "2], ["3", "4"], ["5", "6"]]`

I want to see if the number "4" is in the variable

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder what do you mean?

Comment: You should show what you have tried to solve the problem you have.

Answer (score 2):

You may do [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
const array = [["1", "2"], ["3", "4"], ["5", "6"]],

      result = array.flat().includes('4')
      
console.log(result)
```

Above is easily adjustable (by passing *flattening* depth as a parameter to `flat()`) to nearly any depth of nesting.

If that's just 2 levels deep, you may go for more performant combination of [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
const array = [["1", "2"], ["3", "4"], ["5", "6"]],

      result = array.some(a => a.includes('4'))
      
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const array = [["1", "2"], ["3", "4"], ["5", "6"]];
const value = '4';
/*
 * const result = (new RegExp(value,'gi')).test(array.join()) 
 * result will be true for `4` , `44` , `444` ...
 */

/*
 * to get the exact match we have to use word boundary
 */
const result = (new RegExp(`\\b${value}\\b`,'g')).test(array.join())
```

[Word boundary: \b](https://javascript.info/regexp-boundary)

Comment: Your code will return unexpected result when there's no `'4'`, but `'44'` is present.

Comment: Thanks @YevgenGorbunkov , I have to add the word boundary.

Answer (score -2):

```
function CheckNumberInArray(array, number) {
    FoundNumber = False;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (var j=0; j < array[i].length;j++) {
          if (array[i][j] == number) {
              FoundNumber = true;   // Found it
          }
        }
    }
    return FoundNumber;   // Not found
}
```

Comment: Your code has 2 syntax errors: capital 'F' in `false` and missing closing curly brace for `if(` statement body

Comment: ...Also, for performance considerations (the only reason to justify such verbosity level), I would get rid of `FoundNumber` variable and do `return true` inside `if(` body and `return false` otherwise.